# Pausing appending of Text for a certain number of milliseconds

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I'm currently making a text based game, but I need the calls to pause for a certain number of milliseconds. I'm looking for something like this:

```
void InitProgram()
{
   WriteToText("Welcome!");
   CreatePause(3000); // Pause execution HERE for 3 seconds without locking UI
   WriteToText("How are you?"); // Continue
   StartTutorial();
}
```

So like, the method will be called, do its waiting thing, and then return. And when it returns, normal execution is continued.
What can I do for this effect?

Comment: "without locking UI" thank you.

Comment: Run this method in a separate thread, put Thread.Sleep(3000).

Comment: That doesn't work, it runs it on a separate thread, which means execution of the main thread runs normally.

Comment: @Daaksin No, that would do nothing. What are you working with WPF or Winforms?

Comment: @AhmedKRAIEM Winforms

Comment: Are you targetting FW 4.0 or better? Then (with VS2012) you can use `Await Task.Delay(duration);`

Answer (score 2):

You could use a timer:

```
readonly Timer _timer = new Timer();

void InitProgram()
{    
    WriteToText("Welcome!");

   _timer.Interval = 3000;
   _timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
   _timer.Start();
}


void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WriteToText("How are you?"); // Continue
    StartTutorial();

    _timer.Stop();
}
```

If you wanted to call this multiple times, just put _timer.Start into it's own method, every time you call it, 3 seconds later whatever is in timer_Tick will happen:

```
private void StartTimer()
{
    _timer.Start();
}

void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WriteToText("How are you?"); // Continue
    StartTutorial();

    _timer.Stop();
}
```

Comment: Yes, this could work too. But I believe it is the same problem is the answer below you... What if I wanted to call this multiple times? Maybe even pause before a method? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If target framework is 4.0 or higher and IDE is VS2012 or higher, then you can use async/await

```
    private async void Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Going to Await");
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        Console.WriteLine("Done with awaiting");
    }
```

It's pretty simple and straightforward and the biggest advantage is, that your "linear" flow is kept, because the necessary callbacks etc are handled by the compiler automatically.

Comment: This is amazing, yeah. And very simple. Unfortunately... I'm targeting .NET 2.0, because all Windows PCs use 2.0 out of the box. Thanks though!

Comment: @Daaksin - Different versions of windows comes with different versions of .net... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework#Versions

Comment: As WaraithNath already said: Newer versions of Windows will NOT automatically have "older" versions of the framework installed by default. So the question is: Do you want users with old Windows to download FW 4 (client version) or do you want users with new Windows to download FW 2.0?

Comment: @igrimpe I am not really bothered as to which Framework they use as long as they don't have to run all over the internet looking to download all these extra packs and frameworks and addons just to use my app. That's my only concern.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

Its all pseudo code, I have not tested...

```
Thread _thread;

void InitProgram()
{
   WriteToText("Welcome!");

   ThreadStart ts = new ThreadStart(StartThread);
   _thread = new Thread(ts);
   _thread.Start();
}

private void StartThread()
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.Sleep(3000);
    this.Invoke(delegate { this.StartTutorial(); });
}

private void StartTutorial()
{
   WriteToText("How are you?"); // Continue

   //Start tutorial
}
```

Comment: Yes, this could work. However, the complicated setup required for just one execution could get tiring when you need to call the method for other jobs too. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Hahahahhaha! I figured out the answer using possibly the most crazy method available! Check this out, guys!

First, declare global List:

```
private List<Action> actionList = new List<Action>();
```

Now, this is what you do in the method you wish to call wait from:

```
WriteToLog("Hello!"); 
Action act = delegate() { WriteToLog("How are you?"); }; actionList.Add(act); // Create a new Action out of this method and add it to the action list!
CreatePause(3000); // Call the method with your specified time

void CreatePause(int millisecondsToPause)
    {
        Action w = delegate() { Thread.Sleep(millisecondsToPause); };
        for (int i = 0; i < actionList.Count; i++) // Iterate through each method in the action list that requires attention
        {
            Action a_Instance = (Action)actionList[i]; // Add a cast to each iteration
            AsyncCallback cb = delegate(IAsyncResult ar) { Invoke(a_Instance);  w.EndInvoke(ar); };   // Do each method!!!!
            w.BeginInvoke(cb, null);
        }
        actionList.Clear();  // Clear that list!
        return; // Return!
    }
```

To be honest, this shouldn't work, but it does.

Comment: @igrimpe Check this out!

Comment: There are many methods to achieve what you want - just none is as elegant as the new async/await feature. If I would be bound to FW < 4.0 I'd choose the timer solution as shown by JMK. I'd probably put all into one method to avoid that code that "belongs together" is scattered over several places.

Comment: @igrimpe How can I go about putting that in one easy-to-call method?

Comment: There is a reason, why I prefer FW 4.x ;)

Comment: @igrimpe Hahahahahaha, true that! Is there a way to distribute 4.x with it, then?

Comment: The most user-friendly way, should be the ClickOnce installer. In the server-side setup you can define requirements (and where to automatically download them!), automatic updates etc. The only "disadvantage" is, that it is installed "per user" and not "per computer" - afaik, because I only played around a short time.